# Running Vivaldi with autostart and start Spotify

Tags: pi-4, vivaldi

my aim is to use my Raspberry Pi 4 as a music box with Spotify.
I have installed Vivaldi Browser and it already starts automatically when I start my Raspberry, but still, Spotify is not the standard page when I open it.

I have chosen the way to add a vivaldi.desktop file in `/etc/xdg/autostart` with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Vivaldi
Comment=Vivaldi with Spotify
NoDisplay=false
Exec=vivaldi
```

It works so far, but I would need more parameters under Exec to:

1. close all open tabs in the browser on opening it.
2. open Spotify and if possible
3. press play.

Would be happy if anyone can help me. Thanks!
Maria

Comment: Welcome. The XDG desktop files don't have any special relationship to the applications they launch; you can't do anything with them you couldn't do with the command line.  Ie., there cannot be some special parameter to control the application in a way that can't be done with command line arguments.  So what you really need to find out are the parameters to `vivaldi` (try  `vivalid --help` or `man vivaldi`).  These are not going to include things like "click on some button in the web page", so "press play" is out, unless you find additional software to do that (perhaps vivalid has plugins?).

Comment: Anyway, questions about how to use vivaldi are more appropriate to our larger sibling site, [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or perhaps [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) -- or better yet, *a vivaldi forum*, which glancing at their web page appear to exist.  Other users of that should be able to tell what you need to know quickly.  If you wait for another vivaldi user here, you will be waiting for a long, long time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was easy to open spotify automatically,
Exec=vivaldi https://open.spotify.com/
in the file was enough.
Still looking for a list of possible parameters for vivaldi, but this problem is solved.
Thanks, Maria

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.